# what is the recommended way to use `not` in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have observed that both of the following expression works and would like to know which is the recommended way to use and why?

```py
>>> not(True)
False
>>> not True
False
```

Coming from functional programming background (I have experience in R), I am more inclined to use the first way. Is that accepted or are there any downfalls to it?

Comment: While both are valid in syntax second usage is more common. it is simpler and shorter. However, using not with boolean literals is not a good practice. Use   False instead of not True.

Comment: Both cases of usage of  `not(True)` and `not True` instead of just `False` do not make any sense to me. Generally you could use not necessary braces in many other cases to for example increase readability by not relying on operator precedence or left-to-right processing. Why are you asking? Do you expect a difference going beyond existence of the two spare braces in the source code? Why do you expect such a difference?

Comment: Worth saying that `not` is an operator, not a function. For example, if I really wanted to, I could do `y = print` then `y('hi')`, and it would do the same as `print('hi')`. That's because `print` is a function. But `y = not` is a syntax error.

Comment: Out of interest, do you write `!(TRUE)` instead of `!TRUE` when you use R? (Both are syntactically valid.)

Comment: If you were coming from eLisp ... you would tend to use not necessary braces everywhere possible :D ,like `x=(5); y=(7); z=(1*(1*(1*(x+y))))` (all valid Python syntax you could use in order to get a familiar look ...). There a zillion other ways of obfuscating code in Python next to using unnecessary braces ...

Comment: Here even more "lispic" valid Python code: >>> (exec("x=5")); (exec("y=7")); (1*sum((x,y))) # gives 12 in interactive Python ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so why *would* you use `not(True)`  or more generally `not(x)`?

The syntax `a(b)` would normally be read as a function call on a function `a` with a parameter `b`.

But `not` is not a function and `not(x)` is not a function call.  In Python `not` is a built-in *operator* and it cannot be overloaded.  The brackets are redundant.

So, no matter what your intention is in using that syntax, `not(x)` would only serve to *misdirect* someone with a normal understanding of Python.  This is not *pythonic*.

Comment: Note: sometime we use unnecessary parenthesis but as `not (expr)` (note the space), when there is an expression, to make clear the intent. But with `not` you may make things much more confusing `not(0) + 1` is really `not((0) + 1)`. So parenthesis may just confuse more, (use `(not 0) + 1` ). So avoid parenthesis!

Answer (score 0):

The more "pythonic" way would be the second option without parenthesis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Types - Boolean Operations - and, or, not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **`not x`** - if x is false, then `True`, else `False`

So, the preferred form is **without** the parentheses.
The reasons could be:

- Parentheses indicate a function call
- Readability / simplicity (personal guess)

[[Python.PEPs]: PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008) also contains some examples.

*P.S.*: Seems like [[ReadTheDocs.Black]: The Black code style](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#the-black-code-style) is happy with both forms:

> ```
> (py_pc064_03.08_test0_lancer) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q077252899]> . ~/sopr.sh 
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> python -m black -c "not True"
> not True
> [064bit prompt]> python -m black -c "not (True)"
> not (True)
> [064bit prompt]> python -m black -c "~ 1"
> ~1
> ```

Comment: @KellyBundy: There are some examples there (to prove other things, but still): `if not seq:`.

Comment: Yeah, I realized what you meant. At first I was looking for rules about parentheses and didn't find relevant ones